# Windows search for a given directory containing a given file

Tags: windows, search, find

So, I have an old project, let's call it `my_project`.

Now, I would like to work on it again, but I find that the file `index.html` is missing.

I have extensive backups, including `k:\backups\localhost\weekly\XX\`, where XX is a number between 1 and 52.

Unfortunately, many other projects have a file called `index.htmll`.

So, how do I I search for `k:\backups\weekly\XX\my_project\index.html` ? And not find all of those other `index.html` from many other projects (times 52) ?

It would be a bonus to find the newest, but I can always run a file compare on those that I do find.

Comment: You open k:\backups\weekly\XX\my_project and use the Explorer search field to search for what you want.

Comment: But then I have to open 52 folders :-(  I want to do it with a single command. Was my question not clear? If so, please tell me and I will update it.  But, it does say "`where XX is a number between 1 and 52`"

Comment: Ah ok, you could use something like this in the command prompt:

Comment: for /l %a in (1,1,52) do dir /a /b  k:\backups\weekly\%a\my_project\*WhateverYouWantToFind*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like this in the command prompt:

```
for /l %a in (1,1,52) do dir /a /b k:\backups\weekly\%a\my_project\*WhateverYouWantToFind*
```

Comment: Thanx a 1,000,000